# Is there a way to have multiple router-links inside a li and that li gets the active class in vue2?

Tags: vue-component, vue-router, vue.js

Is there a way to have multiple router-links inside a li and that li gets the active class in vue2?

I was thinking in something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/tejitak/o44z47ag/5/

```
<div id="app">
  <ul>
   <li>
     <ul v-link-active>
       <li>
         <a v-link="{ path: '/foo' }">Go to Foo</a>  
       </li>
       <li>
         <a v-link="{ path: '/bar' }">Go to Bar</a>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a v-link="{ path: '/baz' }">Go to Baz</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

It's supposed to be used in a menu which as submenus.

The migration docs only references a single link so I don't know if this is possible: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration-vue-router.html#v-link-active-replaced

Answer (score 2):

You can use `router-link` like this to do that:

```
<ul>
  <router-link tag="li" to="/foo">
    <span>
      <strong>
        <a>/foo</a>
      </strong>
    </span>
  </router-link>
</ul>
```

Here's the documentation for vue-router: http://router.vuejs.org/en/

Here's the documentation for `router-link`: http://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-link.html

Here's a demo for nested `router-link`s: https://jsfiddle.net/wx17jh2y/

```
<ul>  
  <router-link tag="li" to="/foo">
    <span><a>Foo</a></span>
    <ul>
      <router-link tag="li" to="/bar">
        <span><a>bar</a></span>
      </router-link>  
    </ul>
  </router-link>    
</ul>
```

Comment: but I want the li to have multiple links inside because there could exist submenus!

Comment: That's fine. As long as a `router-link` only has one `<a>` you're good. Nest as much as you'd like. I'll add a demo.

Comment: but how can foo have an active class when bar is active? that's what I'm trying to do

Comment: If the urls are like `/foo` and `/foo/bar` then you get that for free: https://jsfiddle.net/wx17jh2y/2/

Comment: that solves the problem but what should I do if I don't want the first li having any sort of router-link like https://jsfiddle.net/wx17jh2y/2/ ? How can I change the active class from that li? It's impossible?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, I've posted the wrong jsfiddle link! jsfiddle.net/m0qxrqq7 I want the li that has the id "this" to have an active class when my path is /foo/bar. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to group multiple links underneath one element that should be considered active (e.g. using Bootstrap dropdowns), you can just make the parent element a `router-link` as well and prevent any interaction by setting the `event` attribute to an empty list. Example:

```
<router-link tag="li" to="/function" :event="[]">
  <ul>
    <router-link tag="li" to="/function/a"><a>Function A</a></router-link>
    <router-link tag="li" to="/function/b"><a>Function B</a></router-link>
  </ul>
</router-link>
```

See also the documentation on the [`event` property on `router-link`](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-link.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would not use `router-link` and instead bind to the `href` attribute on the anchor tags. If the links in the menu are static, then you may not even need to bind to the `href` attribute - just specify `href="/foo"` (at least that's how it worked in angular1). If the href needs to be generated, like if you're looping through menu items, then create the hrefs in a vue instance function and call it like `:href="createHref(menuItem)"` for example.

To assign the active class, I would assign the class if the href matches the current route (see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html). The current route is in `this.$route`. Just make sure `route` is passed into the root app instance: https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/component-injections.html